# Carbon Sequestration For Indoor Farming

Tags: food-chemistry, environmental-chemistry, atmospheric-chemistry, carbon-dioxide

First the backstory:

We've begun growing mushrooms (currently Enoki, Lion's Mane and Blue Oysters if anyone is curious) for the sake of eating and maybe potentially selling someday soon. My partner and I have a combined diplomas and degrees in Biotechnology, so we know about all the rigors of keeping things clean and contamination free, figured it was time to try our hand at what we've learned and see how well we can do it.

Anyways I got to thinking, what if I grew them in a more oxygen rich environment? I've made the assumption that, like the dinosaurs, an oxygen-rich environment would allow the fungi to grow larger than they would without extra oxygen.

Here's the idea:

At a job I used to work at, we would sequester CO2 in about 0.5M NaOH in order to measure methane gas composition percentages in digesters. The gas was composed of mostly CO2 and CH4. By sequestering one, we can roughly calculate the other. For volumes we'd use about half of the volume of gas in 0.5M NaOH to sequester (not sure if that volume/concentration is the most effective). Shake the solution in the gas and equalize the gas to find out your CH4 percentage.

I'm wondering if I could build, in the most basic sense, a vacuum with an internal NaOH atomizer that pulls outside air through, sequesters the CO2 in liquid, and allows higher concentrations of oxygen to pass into the grow room. As for actually capturing and storing the CO2, I'm thinking I could pass the NaOH through activated biochar and reuse the NaOH or maybe there's a way to precipitate the CO2?

I understand the materials required all need to be compatible with NaOH, especially the atomizer, so it's a bit of a pipe dream. But have I just thought up an effective way to sequester CO2? My minds racing that this may actually be a good idea!

Open to all suggestions and recommendations. I'm not flying forward with this idea at all, so don't worry about me dunking an atomizer in a  bath of NaOH (which no one should !EVER! do unless in an incredibly well-ventilated area, and the equipment is compatible).

First time using this site, hopefully this wasn't too long winded, apologies if I've taken up your lunch break.

Comment: Would it be simpler to buy tanks of compressed Oxygen gas and just pump that into the grow room?

Comment: User $137$ is right. Furthermore, sequestering $\ce{CO2}$ from air will not concentrate the remaining oxygen amount in air. There is about $20$% $ \ce{O2}$  in air, and this proportion will not change if you remove $\ce{CO2}$ from air.

Comment: I agree with user137 and Maurice, at 140 ppm or so of carbon dioxide, unless it inhibits growth, taking it out of the air may not do much.  How about generating oxygen!  Electrolysis?  There seem to be a number of DIY approaches for oxygen generation on youtube - which I must admit I have not screened or viewed for the best approach.

Comment: You need to check back to your biology books about the dinosaurs. What you write about their size and oxygen is just pure nonsense.